# Precache react components using workbox 3.0

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, service-worker, workbox

I am trying to precache the different components of my react app(using the route path) in the workbox 3.0 precache. But only the index.html gets precached without the content of the div tag which varies from page to page
i) React routes

```
        <div className="container">
          <Route exact path="/initial" component={Initial} />
          <Route exact path="/receive" component={Receive} />
          <Route exact path="/deliver" component={Deliver} />
        </div>
```

ii) workbox-config.js

```
  globPatterns: [
"**/*.{json,ico,html,js,css,woff2,woff}",
"/",
"/receive",
"/initial"
 ]
```

I know i am committing a mistake. WHere and how to declare the paths so that it will get precached.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your workbox configuration. If you read the docs [How to Register a Regular Expression Route](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#how_to_register_a_regular_expression_route) you will get an idea on how to handle routes.

Comment: I will go through it. Have you used service-worker for any SPA  project?

Comment: I'm developing a score gaming app that implements registerRoute to cache webfont, images and external API requests. Similar to the worker of this awesome project that helped me to understand the service-worker concept: https://github.com/bob-lee/react-joanne/blob/master/src/sw-template.js

Comment: When I was working on the app, my first solution to implement a service-worker on React followed the structure of the project previously mentioned. But I found a better  solution explained in this article that I wrote: [Using Workbox with Create React App (Without Ejecting)](https://medium.com/@kevinah95/using-workbox-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting-b02b804854b)